# Grails - How can a controller join two tables and display on one gsp?

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-controller

I have two tables (but all of them are installed as plugin) T1, and T2

In T1, columns are: 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d

In T2, columns are: 2a, 2b, 2c, 2d

I need to select columns *a, *b, *c, *d (*=1,2) from both of the tables in a controller as union and sort all of them by the column *d, how can I do that?

After this, how can the pagination work as treating about result as a single table?

I am fairly new to Grails and I am a bit confused about this. Pls help. Appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate, and by extension, grails, has no support for unions.  You'll have to write a raw SQL query to do it that way.

A better approach might be to just simply join the two tables, getting a result set with columns `a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2` and implement the union logic in code.  By sticking with a regular GORM query, you'll be able to use the [built-in pagination](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4%20Querying%20with%20GORM).

Comment: Yeah... extracting information from a single table... I know how to do that... but from multiple tables... I am just looking for a easy way to achieve that... otherwise... it looks like... Grails is stopping me from convenience rather than providing me convenience... :(